# Tomcat connection pool timeout not honoured

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

I am using tomcat jdbc connection pool and the datasource.getConnection() takes very long time occasionally.

I have set  pool.setMaxWait(10000) which means that if I don't get a connection back back from pool in 10 seconds then I should receive an exception.

However I can see that the connection returns back after long time (around 15 minutes i.e. 90000 milliseconds).

Why am i not getting timeout exception?
Am I missing anything?

Below is my pool configuration:

```
    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
    String url = String.format("jdbc:db2://%s:%s/%s", conn.getServer(),conn.getPort(), conn.getDatabase());
    p.setUrl(url);
    p.setDriverClassName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    p.setUsername(conn.getUser());
    p.setPassword(conn.getPassword());

    p.setJmxEnabled(true);
    p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
    p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1");
    p.setTestOnReturn(false);
    p.setValidationInterval(30000);
    p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
    p.setMaxActive(conn.getPoosize());
    p.setInitialSize(10);
    p.setMaxWait(10000);
    p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
    p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
    p.setMinIdle(10);
    p.setLogAbandoned(true);
    p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
    p.setJdbcInterceptors(
      "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
      "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
    DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
    datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
```

Database: DB2

Application: Core Java

Tomcat jdbc connection pool (tomcat-jdbc-9.0.0.M17.jar)

JDK: 8

Comment: Can anyone please help or give a clue here. I am facing this issue and am not able to make out the reason for this. I am totally stuck our here and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this issue? I seem to be facing the same problem on tomcat-jdbc 9.0.11